# View In Lock Screen and enabledRemoteNotificationTypes - iOS5

Tags: ios, push

I've just ran some tests here on the result returned by

```
-(UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes
```

I'm calling it in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate method and Loging the result.
It works fine when alerts, badges or sounds are set.

However, when only the "View in Lock Screen" setting is set in my app push settings, the `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` still return `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`.

Yes I get that sound, badge and alerts are disabled in the settings but shoudn't we have some way to detect this scenario in the App ?

In other words : How to know that the user only set the "View in Lock Screen" setting for the app ?

Comment: I will if I can't find anything else, but I'm not done yet ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The API only provides information about sounds, badges, and alerts.