# How to show Push Notification permission "Ok" / "Don't Allow" button

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to test several scenario if user pressed OK when alert push notification showed, and pressed "Don't Allow" if it's showed.

Reading from past discussion, you have to uninstalled for a day to get this push permission showed. But it didn't work for me. Anyone know why and how to trigger back push notification permission ?

Comment: try General->Reset->Reset Location & Privacy, hope this help :)

Comment: @HuyNghia tried, it didn't work.

Comment: so try  [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571978/how-to-get-back-allow-push-notifications-dialog-after-it-was-dismissed-once)

Comment: more information for you [reset permission push notifications](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4721090)

Comment: @HuyNghia Thanks for direction. I was able to do using this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21581504/554740

Answer (score 0):

These are the step i used for my past projects:

- 1. Go to setting disable anything that connects to whatever push notifications you are working on.
- 2. Uninstall program
- 3. Change Date time to whatever day (just not the day you have received notification) the further seems to be the better.
- 4. If it is still not working. You need to reset your device.

Comment: I can't install if changing future date. I think Crashlytics do the checking for date & time.

Answer (score 0):

> Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Content and Settings

To make things faster you can create backup in iTunes, right after resetting.
Then after each time you saw "Push Permission" alert - use this backup