# How to RERegister the Push notification in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have problem in app version updates

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

In my older version app I have called above method two times wrongly in `didfinishedlaunch` method, For that I have received the same notification twice. So I have called that method one time only. After that I have uploaded that new version into the app store.

My problem is When a user is newly installed my new version app, It will be good, I have received notification single time.

But I have upgraded the older version to the new version, The above problem is repeated for me.Same Notification shows twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can delete the app and then reinstall it fresh and I think it will ask you about notifications again, of which will be your new code. If not then I guess it depends on your push notification service (e.g Parse etc) where there maybe functionality to then delete a device from the list of registered devices for notifications etc.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i know. but i am asking, after older version upgrade to new version. thats means overlapped the older to new version. is any possible without delete the app.  i referred it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571978/how-to-get-back-allow-push-notifications-dialog-after-it-was-dismissed-once