# will didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will get fired on app updation

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am giving an update to my existing application . I am using push notifications for sending messages to user. I am sending the push token to server when the app calls the delegate "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken". The issue is the client wants to move to a new server with the new updation. Will didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will get fired if an existing user updates the installed application

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the user has allowed notification then the method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will be called everytime the app is opened

Answer (score 0):

Better info in below

[How to get back "Allow Push Notifications" dialog after it was dismissed once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571978/how-to-get-back-allow-push-notifications-dialog-after-it-was-dismissed-once)

[Does the APNS device token ever change, once created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-apns-device-token-ever-change-once-created)

for migration of server, wait for some experts to comment it.

Comment: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will get call if user has allowed.

Comment: do we get this call for update of app (not reinstall) / which means the notification dialog box get called on update?

Comment: Notification dialog box (alert) won't get called sure. I'm saying didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will get called. It gets call on every app launch