# How to reset the Push Notifications permissions alert on MacOS

Tags: macos, push-notification, permissions, system-preferences

I want to reset the permission showed on the system preferences -> notifications page. So I can popup grant permission alert again after reset it.

[image]

I google how to reset it and found a way to reset permission on iOS, but not for MacOS.
([How to get back "Allow Push Notifications" dialog after it was dismissed once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571978/how-to-get-back-allow-push-notifications-dialog-after-it-was-dismissed-once))

Does anyone know how to reset the Push Notifications permissions alert on MacOS?
I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to bring back security popups:
`sudo spctl --reset-default`